# Microsoft Word and Excel mailmerge occassionally cuttting off first letter of final merged content

Tags: excel, ms-word, html-email, mailmerge

I have an excel spreadsheet that contains many columns including ones labeled comment1, comment2, comment3, etc.  Not all the columns for each row will have text. In another column of the spreadsheet I merge all these comment columns together and add additional wording and punctuation.  Here is a sample of the merge formula:
[![image of excel formula
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAjc6.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAjc6.png)
It looks fine in the Excel column and when I use Word to merge to an email, it appears okay 95% of the time.  Occasionally, with no rhyme or reason I can figure out, it drops the C from the word comment at the beginning of each line.  It does not drop any other letter and can be any of the lines from the first comment to the last. 
Like this: 
COMMENT: comment text
COMMENT: comment text
OMMENT: comment text
COMMENT: comment text

I cannot figure out why or how to fix this to save my life.  Any idea would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of concatenating all the cells, you could reference them individually in the mailmerge, with your MERGEFIELDs coded as:

```
{MERGEFIELD Comment1 \b "COMMENT: "}{MERGEFIELD Comment2 \b "¶
COMMENT: "}{MERGEFIELD Comment3 \b "¶
COMMENT: "}{MERGEFIELD Comment4 \b "¶
COMMENT: "}
```

where 'Comment1' through 'Comment1' are your comment field names.

**Note:** The field brace pairs (i.e. '{ }') for the above example are all created in the document itself, via Ctrl-F9 (Cmd-F9 on a Mac or, if you’re using a laptop, you might need to use Ctrl-Fn-F9); you can't simply type them or copy & paste them from this message. Nor is it practical to add them via any of the standard Word dialogues. The spaces represented in the field constructions are all required. Instead of the ¶ symbols, you should use real line/paragraph breaks.

Comment: This sounds promising, but how would it allow me to skip blank cells?  Not all rows are going to have comments in all cells

Comment: If you use fields coded as described, the blank cells *will* be skipped...

Comment: Wonderful! THANK YOU! It worked.  I just wish I knew what the problem was with my initial concatenation and there was an easier way to reference the cells.  With up to 48 possible comment cells, that is a lot of typing!

Comment: @learning_curve Actually, you should be able to handle most of the work with simple copy/paste actions, changing only the # in 'Comment3' in each field. In reality, this makes it simpler than your Excel formula. To simplify things, just make sure you have Word's field code display toggled 'on' (Alt-F9 toggles it on/off).